# Обратиться к столбцам DataFrame, вычисляя столбцы с помощью функции

Tags: dataframe, r

Есть таблица "data" со столбцами "A" "B" "C" "D".
Были выбраны признаки "A" и "C" как наиболее взаимосвязанные с признаком "D"
Необходимо построить линейную модель для прогнозирования столбца "D" по значениям "A", "C".
Есть список "groups", в котором в группе с названием "D" лежат строки "A", "C".

Как в формулу построения модели загнать эти названия не вручную, а выбрав их из этого списка с помощью индексации?

Что-то в духе
 `model <- lm(names(groups)[i] ~ groups$names(groups)[i][j] + groups$names(groups)[i][j + 1])`
?

Попробовал применить eval -- видимо, у нее не тот функционал, который ожидал увидеть.
Можно было бы через вычисление индекса вхождения имени списка в имена DataFrame, но это громоздко, не покидает ощущение, что можно короче.

Имена груп -- то, чтонужно спрогнозировать, параметры "D", элементы групп -- прогнозирующие факторы.
[image: Содержимое списка]